# The Lie Algebra and Tangent Space proof in Brain Hall

Tags: proof-explanation, lie-groups

> **Corollary 3.46.**
>   Suppose $G \subset \operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{C})$ is a matrix Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.
>   Then a matrix $X$ is in $\mathfrak{g}$ if and only if there exists a smooth curve $\gamma$ in $\operatorname{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $\gamma(t) \in G$ for all $t$ and such that $\gamma(0) = I$ and $\mathrm{d}\gamma/\mathrm{d}t|_{t=0} = X$.
>   Thus, $\mathfrak{g}$ is the **tangent space at the identity** to $G$.
>
> *Proof.*
>   If $X$ is in $\mathfrak{g}$, then we may take $\gamma(t) = e^{tX}$ and then $\gamma(0) = I$ and $\mathrm{d}\gamma/\mathrm{d}t|_{t=0} = X$.
>   In the other direction, suppose that $\gamma(t)$ is a smooth curve in $G$ with $\gamma(0) = I$.
>   For all sufficiently small $t$, we can write $\gamma(t) = e^{\delta(t)}$, where $\delta$ is a smooth curve in $\mathfrak{g}$.
>   Now, the derivative of $\delta(t)$ at $t = 0$ is the same as the derivative of $t \mapsto t \delta'(0)$ at $t = 0$.
>   Thus, by the chain rule, we have
>   $$
>     \gamma'(0)
>   = \left.
>       \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} e^{\delta(t)}
>     \right|_{t=0}
>   = \left.
>       \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} e^{t \delta'(0)}
>     \right|_{t=0}
>   = \delta'(0).
> $$
>   Since $\delta(t)$ belongs to $\mathfrak{g}$ for all sufficiently small $t$, we conclude (as in the proof of Theorem 3.20) that $\delta'(0) = \gamma'(0)$ belongs to $\mathfrak{g}$.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWHIq.png).)

The conclusion say $\delta \in \mathfrak{g} \implies \delta'(0) \in \mathfrak{g}$. So why does the derivative belong to $\frak{g}$ too?

Answer (score 0):

Since Lie algebra is a linear space, we suppose $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$.

$\delta(t)\in \mathfrak{g}$, so we have $\delta(t)=\sum_{j=1}^nf_j(t)v_j$.

It's obvious that $\delta'(t)|_{t=0}=\sum_{j=1}^nf_j'(0)v_j\in \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: So when we take the derivative, why doesn't that pass over to the basis elements $v_i$?

Comment: The basis element $v_i$ is a constant matrix. For example, $sl(2,\mathbb{R})=span\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\}.$

Comment: What's the reasoning behind $\delta(t)$? How do we know we can write $\gamma(t) = e^{\delta(t)}$?